# Spring boot testing with testNG and gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, testng

my spring boot application is built by Gradle and I am using TestNG and allure for testing and reporting. 
  When I use `gradlew clean test` to test and try to generate test report by using `gradlew allureServe` in IDEA Terminal, I got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.
  My build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "2.1.1.RELEASE"
        springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RELEASE'
        lombokVersion = "1.18.2"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "http://maven.zoom.us/content/groups/public" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
}

plugins {
id 'java'
id 'maven'
id "io.qameta.allure" version "2.7.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
    url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    compile("io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.1.3.RELEASE")
    compile("org.redisson:redisson:3.10.2")
    compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-testng', version: '2.9.0'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.1.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.4.2")
    compile("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:0.13.2")

    testCompile("org.testng:testng:6.11")
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.1.RELEASE'
}
group = 'xxx'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'xxx'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

allure {
    version = '2.9.0'
    autoconfigure = true
    aspectjweaver = true
    useTestNG {
    version = '2.9.0'
    }
}


test {
    useTestNG {
        suites 'src/test/resources/api.xml'
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

and test case looks like:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = RedisdemoApplication.class)
public class SimpleControllerImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private RedissonClient redissonClient;

    @Test
    public void testRedisson() {
        RBucket bucket = redissonClient.getBucket("bucket");
        System.out.println(bucket.isExists());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvoke() {
         System.out.println("testInvoke");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalculateAverageTime() {
        System.out.println("testCalculateAverageTime");
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I configured improperly? Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: Well, your spring boot and spring cloud versions are not compatible